# How to make recursive functions work with react-redux?

Tags: javascript, recursion, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm using redux and react-redux in a react-native audio player app. It involves looping through an array of audio files to play them one by one. I'm using a recursive function to dispatch player actions. But the recursion doesn't get called. Here's some code to explain what I mean:

```
export function playFile(sectionInfo, sectionArray) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const filePath = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/courseSections/' + sectionInfo.section.section_id + '.mp3' 
    Playing = new Sound(filePath,'', error => {
      if(error) {
        return
      }
      dispatch(getPlayDuration(Playing.getDuration()))
      playPlayList(sectionInfo, sectionArray, dispatch)
    })
  }
}

function playPlayList(sectionInfo, sectionArray, dispatch) {
      dispatch(setCurrentPlaySession(sectionInfo.section))
      dispatch(setPlayList(sectionArray))
      Playing.play((success) => {
      console.log('finished playing ')
      Playing.release()
      dispatch(completedSection(sectionInfo.section))
      sectionArray = sectionArray.slice(1)
      if(sectionArray.length > 0) {  //move to next file in playlist if playlist hasn't ended
        playFile(sectionArray[0],sectionArray) //play next file in playlist
      }
    })
}
```

The above are in my actions file. And then in the UI component I connect `playFile` function to props:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ playFile }, dispatch)
}
```

I'm able to trigger the `playFile` function once from the component to play the first file. And then it just stops. I guess this is because when `playFile` is called from `playPlayList`, it loses the dispatch variable? But then I tried calling `playFile(sectionArray[0],sectionArray, dispatch)` in `playPlayList`, it still didn't work.

Would very much appreciate any insights on this, or if I should write it in some completely different way.

Comment: `playFile` seems to return a function. I think you need to do something like `playFile(sectionArray[0],sectionArray)(dispatch)`

Comment: @Titus Oh that's right! Thank you so much! It's working now.